# Spinner Switch Case Problem

Tags: android

EDIT: i have added in all of my code (excluding package and imports.....) and if i try to run it it crashes...... any ideas why?

```
public class BaseConverter extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
int inputBase;
int outputBase;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner input_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.InputSpinner);
    Spinner output_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.OutputSpinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.base_numbers_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    input_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    output_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    input_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new InputItemSelectedListener());

    output_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OutputItemSelectedListener());
}

public class InputItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id)
        {
        /*  switch (Integer.parseInt(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString())
            case ((Integer)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)).intValue(); 
                inputBase = 2;
                break;
            case 8:
                inputBase = 8;
                break;
            case 10;
                inputBase = 10;
                break;
            case 16;
                inputBase = 16;
                break;
                */

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected input base " +
                parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) 
    {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}

public class OutputItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) { 
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected output base " +
          parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

}

and now need to have a switch - case scenario that all revolves around what the value they selected it. they are all numbers (the choices) and are stored in an Integer array. How do i set up that switch-case correctly? i tried doing a simple thing like

```
 case ((Integer.parseInt(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString())
```

Comment: Did you try `((Integer)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)).intValue()`, or even `(int) ((Integer)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos))` ?

Comment: uh no. im totally new to this so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured it out. you need to make the array a STRING array and the use:
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter

etc.....

then use

```
Integer.parseInt(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
```

to find the numerical value of whatever you selected. NOTE: it must be all numerical or it will give you an error.