# How to use Cases for a spinnerlist?

Tags: java, android, spinner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spinner Switch Case Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476379/spinner-switch-case-problem)

I want to use Cases for SpinnerList but i doesn't work for me, i searched the internet but no answer helped.

```
 public void onMyButtonClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos)  
 {                          

        EditText tstrenght = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Tstrenght);
        //String hello = et.getText().toString();
        int in2 = new Integer(tstrenght.getText().toString());
        EditText scap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Scap);
        //String hello = et.getText().toString();
        int in1 = new Integer(scap.getText().toString());
     TextView Uitkomst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uitkomst);
     Uitkomst.setText("0.00");
     switch (Integer.parseInt(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()) {
                case R.string.Scap_prompt = 4:
                {

                    float uitkomst = (float) (((Math.sqrt(7200/(in2)))*100)/100);
                    Uitkomst.setText((String.valueOf(uitkomst)) + " mm");

                    //break;

                }
            }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the Switch/Case correctly.

The switch statement tells what you are going to check, and that looks ok, but the case should just be a value (which is compared to the switch statement), there shouldn't be a comparison in the case.  (Especially one that makes no sense...  R.String.Scap_prompt is a constant and you are comparing it to a constant, so it will always evaluate the same way).

This is what a switch/case should look like:

```
switch (Integer.parseInt(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()) {           
    case 4:           
    {           
        float uitkomst = (float) (((Math.sqrt(7200/(in2)))*100)/100);           
        Uitkomst.setText((String.valueOf(uitkomst)) + " mm");           
        //break;           
    }           
 }
```

Comment: Post the logcat so we can see what the error is.

Comment: The Button stays yellow and nothing is responding. The app isn't Force Quitting. I don't know where to find the logcat.

Comment: If it's not doing anything then none of your cases match the switch.  Run in debug mode and take a look at what you are getting for `Integer.parseInt(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()`

Comment: in the spinner i don't have only 4 but 4 mm, but if i change the case it gives a error

Comment: Yes, you can only use integers in a switch in the compiler levels that can be used to compile Android apps.  Change the switch statement. Strip the "mm" part off first and then do `Integer.parseInt...` and leave the case alone.  I think that will fix you up.

Comment: in the spinner i removed the "mm" but it's still not working i found the logcat: http://www.sendspace.com/file/zlmhrd

Comment: In this code how does it even know to look at the spinner called Scap_prompt

Comment: I was assuming your button was inside the spinner since you are using `parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)`... if not, then that might be your issue.

Comment: I new to java and used other things on stackflow as base for this such as parent